# Customized cross-reference in a @misc entry type

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I am using `biblatex-chicago`.

I would need to cite [this](http://polisci.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/people/u3827/Teaching%20Process%20Tracing.pdf) very odd bibliographic item — an online-posted supplement to an article published in a peer-reviewed journal.

I think it is only fair to assume that this is one of a kind and that there are no stylistic guidelines for citing this kind of beast, not even in the CMS. For this reason, i opted for a `@misc` entry type.

As to the way it should look in the bibliography, I think it would be appropriate to adopt the citing style reported in the top-right corner of the article linked above:

> Online Teaching Exercises to accompany David Collier (2001), “Understanding Process Tracing.” *PS: Political Science and Politics* 44(4): 823-30.

I would normally include all this in a `titleaddon`, `addendum`, or `note` field.

However, I already have an entry for the 2011 article that the teaching exercises accompany. It would be nice to use the `crossref` field so that the entry would look something like the following in the bibliography:

> … Online Teaching Exercises to accompany Collier (2011).

with a hyperlinked year that links to the appropriate bibliographic entry.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Here's a MWEB:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,cmsdate=both,useprefix=false,ibidtracker=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{collier:understanding_process_tracing,
author = {Collier, David},
title = {Understanding Process Tracing},
journaltitle = {PS: Political Science \& Politics},
year = 2011,
volume = {44},
number = {4},
pages = {823--830},
}

@misc{collier:teaching_process_tracing,
author = {Collier, David},
title = {Teaching Process Tracing},
subtitle = {Exercises and Examples},
titleaddon = {Online Teaching Exercises to accompany \textcite{collier:understanding_process_tracing}},
year = 2011,
pages = {1--15},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\parencite{collier:understanding_process_tracing,collier:teaching_process_tracing,}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This gives the desired result, but I thought that using `crossref` or some related field would be more elegant.

Comment: Please post a MWEB (minimal working example with bibliography) people can work with.

Comment: Why can't you just use e.g. `\textcite{}` in the note field or whatever? The `crossref` field isn't right for this.

Comment: @cfr I most certainly can. I just thought there should be a more elegant solution that uses `crossref` or the like. I will post a MWEB in a minute.

Comment: My best bet would be the `related` function. But since there is no pre-built `related` for "supplementary material to an article" or the like, it would need some new definitions. Not sure how easy they are to get right with `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: I guess I'll stick with `\textcite{}` inside `titleaddon` then.

Comment: @moewe I wondered about that. Though `biblatex-chicago` is a fairly major style, in that it does really a lot of things, which makes the matter rather complex. (Or it did do a lot - I haven't used it for a while.)